# Oracle sql order by not working as expected?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called 'ADDRESSES'.

My query:

```
select MODIFIED_DATE, CITY from ADDRESSES order by MODIFIED_DATE desc, CITY asc;
```

By running the above query I get:

```
MODIFIED_DATE   CITY
=============   ==============
13-JAN-16       CHICAGO
13-JAN-16       CHICAGO
13-JAN-16       CHICAGO
13-JAN-16       KANSAS CITY
13-JAN-16       KANSAS CITY
13-JAN-16       KANSAS CITY
13-JAN-16       KANSAS CITY
13-JAN-16       KANSAS CITY
13-JAN-16       CHICAGO
13-JAN-16       CHICAGO
13-JAN-16       DENVER
13-JAN-16       DENVER
```

But I expect:

```
MODIFIED_DATE   CITY
=============   ==============
13-JAN-16       CHICAGO
13-JAN-16       CHICAGO
13-JAN-16       CHICAGO
13-JAN-16       CHICAGO
13-JAN-16       CHICAGO
13-JAN-16       DENVER
13-JAN-16       DENVER
13-JAN-16       KANSAS CITY
13-JAN-16       KANSAS CITY
13-JAN-16       KANSAS CITY
13-JAN-16       KANSAS CITY
13-JAN-16       KANSAS CITY
```

The data type of MODIFIED_DATE is DATE and the data type of CITY is VARCHAR2.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I would suspect that there is a time component to your `DATE` values, even if it's not being displayed.

Comment: Run this first:  `alter session set nls_date_format='dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss';`  Then re-run your query  ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oracle Date contains more information than displayed : hour, minutes and second. If you are only interested in the date part you should use  `trunc()`

```
order by trunc(MODIFIED_DATE) desc, CITY asc
```